# Error : The type of column "DOB" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, type-conversion, unpivot

MY QUERY,

simply to convert the row into column

```
SELECT
  ColumnName,
  value
FROM (SELECT
  id [ID],
  firstname [First Name],
  lastname [Last Name],
  dob [DOB],
  sex [Gender]
FROM client
WHERE id = '11') d
UNPIVOT
(
Value FOR
ColumnName IN ([ID], [First Name], [Last Name], [DOB], [Gender])
) unpiv;
```

But it showing an error.

> The type of column "DOB" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the result will bring back all columns in rows, building a new derived column with all the values, you must ensure, that the types fit together.

You can wrap all your columns in `CAST`

```
SELECT
  ColumnName,
  value
FROM (SELECT
  CAST(id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) [ID],
  CAST(firstname AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) [First Name],
  CAST(lastname AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) [Last Name],
  CAST(dob AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) [DOB],
  CAST(sex AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) [Gender]
FROM client
WHERE id = '11') d
UNPIVOT
(
Value FOR
ColumnName IN ([ID], [First Name], [Last Name], [DOB], [Gender])
) unpiv;
```

The `DOB` will be converted to the default setting of your machine. Using `CONVERT` you might enforce a given date/time format.